# Query data inside collection

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.2

I am trying to query firms which have category which categoryId field equals my parameter. Here is my code:

These are my models:

```
public class Firm
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<FirmCategory> Categories { get; set; }
}

public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<FirmCategory> Firms { get; set; }
}

public class FirmCategory
{
    public int FirmId { get; set; }
    public Firm Firm { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
var firms =  _context.Firms
    .Include(x => x.Categories)
        .ThenInclude(x => x.Category)
    .AsQueryable();
firms = firms.Where(x => x.Category.CategoryId == param.CategoryId)
```

I know this doesn't work but this is what I would like to achieve with either `AsQueryable()` or with `ToList()`

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my problem by using these commands:

```
var firms = _context.Firms.AsQueryable();

firms = firms
                .SelectMany(x => x.Categories)
                .Where(x => x.CategoryId == param.CategoryId)
                .Select(x => x.Firm)
                .Include(x => x.Categories).ThenInclude(x => x.Category)
                .Include(x => x.Services).ThenInclude(x => x.Service);
                ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `join` to achieve the same goal:

```
var firms = from firm in _context.Firms
    join formCategory in _context.FirmCategories on firm.Id equals formCategory.FirmId
    join category in _context.Categories on formCategory.CategoryId equals category.Id
    where category.Id == param.CategoryId
    select firm;
```

In case you want to load categories for the firms , you could :

```
firms = firms.Include(f => f.Categories).ThenInclude( fc => fc.Category);
```